# How can I deploy Glassfish Maven app on CloudBees?

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, cloudbees

I am trying to deploy a Maven web application on Cloudbees. My app works successfully on Netbeans I  clicked ClickStart and then Glassfish App Server. I created my app. After that I upload my war file. When I open app there is Glassfish default welcome page on my browser not my app. How can I deploy a Glassfish app to Cloudbees?

my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>webserviceCloudBees</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>webserviceCloudBees</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>cloudbees-public-release</id>
            <url>http://repository-cloudbees.forge.cloudbees.com/public-release</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.cloudbees</groupId>
                <artifactId>bees-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you "upload war file" ? As you used a clickstart the expected step is then to retrieve the source code for generated sample application and adapt to your own application then commit. Jenkins will then build and deploy. You also can deploy using cloudbees SDK (or integrated eclipse plugin) from a war, without requirement to use a clickstart.

Comment: First I click CliskStart and then select Glassfish 3 App. And then I give a name for my app. After my app was created, I enter my application center and I select my app. After that I click "Alternatively, upload a WAR file" button and I upload my war file. But my app doesn't work. Is there a any tutorial about it?

Comment: Preferred way to deploy (as clickstarts do) is to push application source code, let jenkins build the adequate package and deploy to RUN@Cloud. Clone the git repo created by clickstart and override the default demo app with your own code